# Max Date between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server

How can I find the latest date in a column but constrain it between 2 dates

```
SELECT [Weight]
FROM [weighinevent] w
WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND w.[userid] = @userid )
```

This is what I have.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Subqueries need to define the table too from which they are selecting. But you can order by the date and take only the first record

```
SELECT top 1 Weight
FROM weighinevent
WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
AND userid = @userid
ORDER BY Date DESC
```